Filament cracks after left untouched
Hi 3D Printer enthusiasts!, I currently use an Ender 3 printer and a Numakers PLA + black filament. Unfortunately, when I finish a print and leave the printer off with the filament attached for a few days, the suspended filament (the gap of filament from the spool to the bowden extruder) begins to crack. I have no idea why this happens and would like help.

How long after you have finished the print do you notice the filament cracking? Do you live in a high-humidity environment?

It’s most likely a humidity issue. I’ve encountered similar problems before. I recommend avoiding exposure of the filament to the environment and storing it in a dry place if you won’t be using it for more than a day. Personally, I keep my filaments in ziplock bags along with silica gel.

This combined with Carl's answer would solve and prevent your problem. Store dry and bake when wet.

This is almost certainly due to your filament being hydrated.  Try baking out the reel at a low oven temp (75 to 125 °C)

That high? I usually go 70 °C for PETG, wouldn't heating PLA+ to those temperatures deform the filament?

@Oscar  Given the melting point  is at least 180, I wouldn't think so, but 70 should work fine, albeit taking a bit longer.
